# How to put a certain message in Try catch VB in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, try-catch

I wanted to trap this condition that when a user input a letter in the contact number textbox it will show a message box and it will say "That is not a valid contact number" here is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        con.Open()
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into pInformation (palName,pafName,pamName,pabirthdate,paaddress,panumber) Values (@lname,@fname,@mname,@birthdate,@address,@number)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", TextBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mname", TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("birthdate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", TextBox4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", TextBox6.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            Me.PInformationTableAdapter.Fill(Me.JoshuadbDataSet1.pInformation)
            MessageBox.Show("Record successfully added.")
        ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save this?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            con.Close()
        End If
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to validate if the contents of `TextBox6` are a valid number you can use the `Integer.TryParse` method.

```
Dim number As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox6.Text, number) Then
  MessageBox.Show("Not a number")
  Return
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the contact number in your code and provide a message rather than sending it to the db to fail and catching the error. Don't use Try Catch to do validation that you can do through normal means.

Edit:

How you should validate the number depends entirely on what range of numbers you  accept. Are you validating numbers purely on *looking* like genuine numbers? If so you may want to use a Regular Expression. Eg...

```
Dim num As String=TextBox6.Text
'Regex to allow only numbers 
Dim rex As Regex=New Regex("^[0-9]+$")
If Not rex.IsMatch(num) Then
    'Alert user of bad number and do not execute SQL call
```

If you actually need to validate the number against numbers already in the database then obviously a call to the database will be necessary, and there is an argument here for using Try Catch and having your database call throw an error signifying the exact problem.

Comment: How could I do it sir?

Comment: See update. I would also advise giving your TextBoxes meaningful names!